# Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel checked all rows on load

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want my `Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel` to be loaded with all checkboxes in the `SelectionModel` checked.

I write this method:

```
function SelectAllRows()
{     
    var sModel = reportsGrid.getSelectionModel();
    sModel.selectAll(true);    
}
```

And try to call it from many places:

```
var xmlStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    url: "...",
    reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({
        record: '...',
        totalRecords: "results"
    },
    record
)
});

xmlStore.on('load', CheckResults);
xmlStore.on('load', SelectAllRows);
xmlStore.load();
```

But only on the first entrance to the page it work well, when I come back from the next page it doesn't work.

It is strange that when I add to the bottom bar a label wich contains the sum of a data of the checked rows, and the label show the sum of all rows! 
So, the method called well, but the checkboxes don't show as checked.

Have you met this problem?

Comment: It could be because you've all the data and the paging is done locally. So because of that load is only called once. I'm assuming you're using Ext.PagingToolbar to switch between pages? Maybe you would want to hook the `SelectAllRows` on the paging toolbar's `change` event?

Comment: I didn't use Ext.PagingToolbar in this grid, 
It seems that the SelectAllRows method been called well, because the BottomToolBar contains the number of all rows (as checked)
But it just doesn't show that they are checked(visual problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw it happened because of the render activated twice,
Added this value -'deferRowRender: false'- to the Ext.grid.GridPanel properties ,
make the checkboxes be marked on every entrance/load of th page.

```
var reportsGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    cm: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
        sm,
        { id: '...', dataIndex: '...', hidden: true },
        { header: '...', width: 200, sortable: true, dataIndex: '...' }
    ]),  
    sm: sm,                  
    deferRowRender: false
});
```